# config.assets.precompile not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline

I have a bookmarklet, which needs separate js and css files - i.e. I don't want them compiled as usual into one file.

These are the files that I want to separate from the usual js and css files:

```
assets/javascripts/bookmarklet/tagger.js
assets/javascripts/bookmarklet/js/bookmarklet.js
assets/stylesheets/bookmarklet/bookmarklet-frame.css
```

In `application.js` and `application.css` I changed `//= require_three .` to `//= require_directory .`

And I added:

```
config.assets.precompile += [ 'bookmarklet/js/bookmarklet.js', 'bookmarklet/tagger.js', 'bookmarklet/bookmarklet-frame.css' ]
```

to my `production.rb` and `staging.rb`.

An `application.js` and `application.css` is generated, however, my three separate files are not. Any idea why this is not working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Had to move

```
config.assets.precompile += [ 'bookmarklet/js/bookmarklet.js', 'bookmarklet/tagger.js', 'bookmarklet/bookmarklet-frame.css' ]
```

to `application.rb`.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you have require_tree instead of require_directory, require_tree adds recursively but require_directory does not. Refer [asset pipeline](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html)

`application.js`

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require_tree .
```

`application.css`

```
/* ...
*= require_self
*= require_tree .
*/
```

`application.html.erb` should have these lines

```
<%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
<%= stylesheet_link_tag "application" %>
```

Now when you precompile the assets with command `RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile`  in your production you will have(all the js files compiled into one, css into one)

`application.html.erb`

```
<script src="/assets/application-908e25f4bf641868d8683022a5b62f54.js"></script>
<link href="/assets/application-4dd5b109ee3439da54f5bdfd78a80473.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" />
```

This is unnecessary as by default application.js, application.css are precompiled.

```
config.assets.precompile += [ 'bookmarklet/js/bookmarklet.js', 'bookmarklet/tagger.js', 'bookmarklet/bookmarklet-frame.css' ]
```

Sometimes you may use `admin.js` for a layout `admin.html.erb` only then you need to add a line like this in production.rb

Comment: Maybe I should have been more clear, but I don't want them compiled into one file. I want the three files I mention compiled into separate files.

Comment: The asset pipeline provides a framework to concatenate and minify or compress JavaScript and CSS assets. It also adds the ability to write these assets in other languages such as CoffeeScript, Sass and ERB.

Making the asset pipeline a core feature of Rails means that all developers can benefit from the power of having their assets pre-processed, compressed and minified by one central library, Sprockets.

So, if you want separate files you should not precompile, basically you don't want assets to be minified.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution to consider where moving to application.rb may not be necessary. Instead, add 'production' to :assets in your config/application.rb. 'production' is by default not included in the list.

```
if defined?(Bundler)
  # If you precompile assets before deploying to production, use this line
  Bundler.require(*Rails.groups(:assets => %w(development test production)))
  # If you want your assets lazily compiled in production, use this line
  # Bundler.require(:default, :assets, Rails.env)
end
```