# Cannot get seperate admin.css file to compile using config.assets.precompile directive

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, asset-pipeline

I have a seperate admin/admin.css file specifically setup for my backend... but it is not compiling on deploy.

assets/stylesheets/admin/admin.css:

```
 *= require_self
 *= require_directory .
 */
```

config/environments/staging.rb

```
config.assets.precompile += %w( admin/admin.css )
```

In my admin layout file:

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag    "admin/admin", media: "all", "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>
```

When i view the admin on server, the admin.css does not have the pipeline file

```
<link data-turbolinks-track="true" href="/stylesheets/admin/admin.css" media="all" rel="stylesheet" />
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/application-52640905a0371910c47f3bbe54ff228b.js"></script>
```

I found this post with a similar problem: [config.assets.precompile not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18061202/config-assets-precompile-not-working). you can see the solution for him was to move the config.assets.precompile directive to the application.rb file. I feel like moving this is not a good solution, as rails puts the directive into the environment file by default.

---

EDIT:
To fix the issue, i had to remove capistrano-faster-assets gem, then it compiled my files. I opened an issue on the gem's github https://github.com/capistrano-plugins/capistrano-faster-assets/issues/3

Answer (score 0):

try moving the file in public/ folder. no more action needed in staging.rb